# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined (calling assignedNodes())

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm working with a custom data table that lets me insert a lookup component in each row. So, I import the lookup template from the same folder as the custom datatable:`import LookupTemplate from './lookupTemplate.html';` The lookup template is like this:

```
<template>
   <c-lookup
       configs={typeAttributes.configs}
       is-lookup={typeAttributes.isLookup}>
       <input class="slds-input" style="color: black;"></input>
   </c-lookup>
</template>
```

The lookup has a slot in its html to put, for example in this case an input.

In the js of the lookup component, this function is called on slot change:

```
handleSlotChange(e) {
    this._input = e.target.assignedNodes()[0];
    e.target.assignedNodes()[0].addEventListener('focus', this.handleFocus.bind(this));
    e.target.assignedNodes()[0].addEventListener('blur', this.handleBlur.bind(this));

    if (this.isLookup) this._input.classList.add("slds-input");

}
```

For some reason, the error in the title is thrown when the component in which I'm using the datatable loads. I've used this lookup component before and this never happened. I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact I'm using it as a template for the datatable, Maybe the template doesn't load in time for the slot change to be able to access the assignedNodes, but how can I fix this?